# Monitor server events and update list in web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, live, monitor

In a list of events I present on a web page I want to offer the feature to get "live" updates in case of an event on the server side. So kind of a live monitor instead of reloading the list in a polling cycle.

I guess I need something like this:

```
- Client: open a socket to the server (ajax like), 
          listening for events, 
          if an event comes, update the visible list.
- Server: if such socket has been opened: 
          propagate any event through that socket.
```

Is there something like a jQuery extension suitable for this purpose ?

Comment: you are looking for 'long polling'. Html5 has websockets for this purpose but if that's not an option then just use a) ne of the widely known longpolling techniques or find a .js framework directly aimed at simplifying long polling

Comment: Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) 
More info [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

But for a simple solution, all you need is define is `setInterval` that sends an ajax request every few seconds/minutes.

```
//runs every 3 seconds
setInterval(function(){
 //do ajax and refresh list
},3000);
```

Of course if the polling should happen very often ,this solution is not very good, in that case you should look at a long polling solution.

Comment: For this application the feature only makes sense if the event is propagated more or less instantly. So polling is not an option. I will check out node.js, thanks !